# OpenDMTP configuration on Linux machine

Tags: c++, c, linux, linker, gps

I've successfully installed and run the OpenGTS server application using the HTTP based GPRMC servlet.

Now I'm attempting to run the OpenDMTP C Client on linux. I get stuck at the very first step.

When I try to use the make command in the terminal:

```
                make dest=linux dmtp
```

I get the following errors:

```
Linking 'dmtpd' ...

cc -o ./build_lin/obj/dmtp/dmtpd -Wall -DTARGET_LINUX -DTRANSPORT_MEDIA_SOCKET -
DPROTOCOL_THREAD -DGPS_THREAD -Isrc /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libpthread.so  /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libm.so ./build_lin/obj/custom/startup.o /build_lin/obj/custom/transport.o ./build_lin/obj/custom/log.o ./build_lin/obj/custom/gps.o ./build_lin/obj/custom/gpsmods.o ./build_lin/obj/custom/linux/os.o -L./build_lin/obj/lib -lmodule -lbase -ltools
    ./build_lin/obj/lib/libbase.a(propman.o): In function _propGetDoubleValue': propman.c:   (.text+0xec8): undefined reference topow'

  propman.c:(.text+0xf0b): undefined reference to pow' 
  ./build_lin/obj/lib/libbase.a(propman.o): In function_propSetDoubleValue':

propman.c:(.text+0xf5b): undefined reference to pow' propman.c:(.text+0xf66): undefined reference torint'

./build_lin/obj/lib/libbase.a(propman.o): In function _propInitKeyValueFromString': 
propman.c:(.text+0x26e4): undefined reference topow'

propman.c:(.text+0x26ef): undefined reference to rint' 
./build_lin/obj/lib/libtools.a(gpstools.o): In functiongpsRadiansToPoint':

gpstools.c:(.text+0x253): undefined reference to sin' gpstools.c:(.text+0x269): undefined reference to cos'

gpstools.c:(.text+0x277): undefined reference to cos' gpstools.c:(.text+0x292): undefined reference to sin'

gpstools.c:(.text+0x2b0): undefined reference to sqrt' gpstools.c:(.text+0x2be): undefined reference to sqrt'

gpstools.c:(.text+0x2cd): undefined reference to atan2'
 ./build_lin/obj/lib/libtools.a(threads.o): In functionthreadCreate':

threads.c:(.text+0x191): undefined reference to `pthread_create'
```

It appears math.h isn't being accessed by the file. I think the program doesn't include the headers from the \usr\include directory but don't know how to add this path to the makefile. Please help!
Please help!

Comment: I would say that whoever created the makefile didn't know what he/she was doing. Some linkers (like the GNU linker most often used in Linux) needs to have dependent object before their dependencies. So if object file O depends on library L, then O must come before L on the command line. If you see the command line generated by Make, you will see that some libraries are placed *before* the object files, like the standard C math library, and the POSIX thread library (libpthread). That's the reason for the errors.